# Is there a way to use the distinct keyword inside a conditional case statement of an SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an SQL statement in which I would like to use the distinct keyword inside a conditional case statement like so...

```
SELECT
  case when <condition> then distinct t.myfield
  else
  null
  end as my_field
```

If I try to run the query, though, I get a 'missing expression' error.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: show table structure, describe what you want to select a expected result data

Comment: You can only apply distinct to the column expression, not to the THEN clause within the CASE.

Comment: If that's the only thing you're selecting, just use select distinct... if not, then you'll have to add more details of what your data + sql is and what you expect as the result

Comment: You tagged this as both MySQL and SQL Server. Could you explain why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Distinct is for the entire select statement, not a single field. You could do the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Case when <condition> then t.myfield else null end as my_field
```

This will affect other fields in the select statement though. An alternative would be to add it to a separate query:

```
SELECT case when <condition> then t.myfield else null end as my_field
from (select distinct myfield from t) as t
```